# What is more optimized way between X>0 or X!=0 in C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, conditional-statements

There are situations when we have a values in a variable say X is that variable and we want to have a if condition and compare if the values is more then 0 then which method will be optimized one.

X>0 or X!=0

Can someone specify with the logic. We can take example in C#.

Comment: The effect of this change will be so minuscule that it won't have any impact unless you repeat it billions of times each second.

Comment: `X!=0` does not check if the value is *more than 0*. It checks if it's not equal to 0. That's a different thing (unless your variable is unsigned). Also, I would be really surprised if that's where a bottleneck of your performance is.

Comment: @Euphoric No impact on speed at all. A billion loops with a i > 0 or i != 0 if statement completed in 0.072 seconds for me.

Comment: @Verkade89 Post detailed description of your testing methodology.

Comment: The real difference is not at all about performance but about good, [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, both statements will finally be mapped to a single CPU instruction

```
jg - jump if greater
jne - jump if not equal
```

Suddenly, your question becomes much more complex, because

- we need to know which CPU exactly will be executing the statement
- whether it's a 8, 16, 32 or 64 bit comparison
- whether it will be a long jump or short jump
- whether it's signed or unsigned

You would need to find that out by not only looking at the IL code but also at the assembly instructions generated by the JIT compiler. This makes it even more complex:

- JIT compilation might depend on the .NET framework version
- the JIT mit re-compile your method on the fly

All in all: do not care. [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it), it's premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, these operators

```
 X > 0 
 X != 0
```

are *not equal*; you actually (in *general case*) should choose between

```
 X > 0 || X < 0
 X != 0
```

explicit and direct comparison `X != 0` is more readable, and slightly faster. In case of build-in types `int`, `float`, `decimal` etc. the performance difference is *negligible*. In case of *user defined* class equations (`==` and `!=`) are usually faster since comparisons (`>`, `<`; `>=`, `<=`) often involve `IComparer<T>`, `IComparable<T>` interfaces with complex algorithms.

Summary: stick to `X != 0`:

1. It's more readable and explicit
2. In case of build-in primitive types the performance is not the concern
3. In case of user defined type, `X != 0` has a good chance to be faster

Comment: It depends on the type. For unsigned values, it could be the same.